# how to reload the toolsrtipcontrol in c#

Tags: c#

how to reload the toolsrtipcontrol in c# or how to trigger toolstrip load event ?

Comment: The question does not make sense. Can you provide more details?

Comment: what i need is to remove all the contents from the toolstrip and add new items to it

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for controls, you can not have them "reload"; events can only be raised by the instance that they belong to, and any initialization of the control happens only once.

The only way to effectively get this event to fire again would be to remove the control, create a new instance with the properties of the old control, and then re-add the control to its container.

However, if you are able to, you might want to subclass the control in question and put your logic in a method that you can call repeatedly and then use instances of *that* control in your application, having the method called when necessary.